# How can I use custom widget in Visual Composer or conversion it to Visual Composer Element?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Visual Composer only show wordpress's widgets. And custom made widget not showing in Visual Composer.
I want to know how can I use custom widget in Visual Composer or conversion it to Visual Composer Element? Or how can I add element for Visual Composer by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.wpelixir.com/how-to-create-new-element-in-visual-composer/
Here is the URL for add the new block of custom code into visual composer block area, this will help you for creating a new element.

Comment: ok , thanks very much. So can't conversion widgets to Visual Composer Element?

Comment: You can use a widget module and add your widget to it.